# Interpreting and using principal components of word embeddings

Tags: python, nlp, pca, word2vec, word-embedding

Imagine you have a set of semantically related words (e.g. restaurant, food, dish, waiter), along with a few relatively unrelated words (e.g. sad, angry, iphone). How would you go about finding these "anomalous" words?

I'm using word vectors (e.g. fasttext, glove) to represent these words and one simple way that works to some extent is to sort the vectors based on their distance from their mean. But this isn't perfect...

I've considered using PCA, but not sure if that is a good approach or how exactly to find the anomalous words using it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's a lot of abstract potential to tackle in an SO question! But it did remind me of this interesting somewhat-related paper/post, where the idea of "discourses" help pull alternate word-senses from word-vectors that were initially trained in a way that was completely oblivious to word-senses and alternate discourses: https://www.offconvex.org/2016/07/10/embeddingspolysemy/ – perhaps that or other work on word-senses (like covered in the survey https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.04032) can trigger some ideas for you.

Comment: Thanks @gojomo, those links are very interesting resources. I do believe that what I want to achieve relates to word senses, but I guess my main question is asked better this way (will edit the post too): how would you apply "anomaly detection" to word vectors? Would PCA work in any way for that (through finding the normal embedding sub-space and detecting "outlier words"?) What other techniques would you recommend?